# Getting Wrong Answer in SPOJ AP3 (AP - Complete The Series)?

Tags: c++, optimization

I am stucked in a problem on SPOJ, [here](http://www.spoj.com/problems/AP3/)

I did the maths for it, and finally coded the [solution](http://ideone.com/OpPGfA).

I get it right on ideone, but SPOJ rejects my answer as "WA".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
typedef long long LL;

using namespace std;

int main() {

        LL t,x,y,sum,d,n,cd,a,i;

        cin>>t;

    while(t--)
    {
        cin >> x >> y >> sum;
        d = 5*y + 7*x + 2*sum;

        n = (d + sqrt(d*d - 48*sum*(x+y)))/(2*(x+y));

        cd = ( y - x )/(n-6);

        a = x - 2 * cd;

        cout<<n<<endl;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            cout<< a + cd * i<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> **Input:**
>
> 3
>
> 3 7 55
>
> 8 11 77
>
> 9 17 120
>
> **Output:**
>
> 10
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>
> 7
>
> 2 5 8 11 14 17 20
>
> 8
>
> 1 5 9 13 17 21 25 29

Where am I getting it wrong. I think that the problem might be the precision, but I am not able to check that. Am i wrong with the data types or the precision used or is some I/O optimization needed? Is the Input [ 5 1 25 ] valid? because it gives output as [ 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 ]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you read the forum? Especially the "use `sqrtl` instead of `sqrt`" part?

Comment: "Probe into functions like llrintl() and sqrtl()" . I can't get proper info on them :/

Comment: Is there some Overflow? how?

Answer (score 0):

hope i am not too late..there are some `precision loss` like you have to first take your answer in `long double` and then convert it to `long long int` type using `llrint()` function..i hadn't solved this problem till now because my math calculations are not yielding correct result..i used your code only to check the result and got `AC`..here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

typedef long long int LL;

using namespace std;

int main() {

        LL t,x,y,sum,i,a,tointeger,newdiff;
        long double n,cd,d;

        cin>>t;

        while(t--) {
            cin >> x >> y >> sum;
            d = 5.0 * y + 7.0 * x + 2.0 * sum;

            n = (d + sqrt(d * d - 48.0 * sum * (x + y))) / (2.0 * (x + y));
            tointeger = llrint(n);

            cd = (y - x) / (tointeger - 6.0);
            newdiff = llrint(cd);
            a = x - 2 * newdiff;
            cout<<tointeger<<endl;

            for(i=0;i<tointeger;i++) {
                cout<< a + newdiff * i<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why this works?
I can't understand where to use `llrint()` and why it's needed when all divisions here are guaranteed to not result in any decimal values.